# Deserialize dynamic json object with arrays to postgres table Using postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, dynamic

"code1": {
"obj1": [ {
"sample_name": "1",
"sample_code": "1",
"sample_serial": "01",
"parameters": [
{
"param1": "param1",
"param2": "param2",
"param3": "param3",
"param4": "param4",
"param5": "param5",
"param6": "param6"
}],
]
}

This is my sample json and I would like to deserialize it dynamically in backend  using postgres .I am able to deserialize for array with "Testdata" but for code "code1": {
"obj1" and so on I am not able to deserialize it . Code 1 , obj1 ,obj2 are dynamically created in Json.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

I tried to DE serialize the array to table . I am expecting to DE serialize the object with arrays `. Also I am able to get all keys from json_object_keys(jsondata) as key in but not able to get the data`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to deserialize a json data depending on its own structure.
Here is one possible solution :

```
SELECT a->>'key' AS key, a->>'value' AS value
  FROM jsonb_path_query('{"code1": { "obj1": [ { "sample_name": "1", "sample_code": "1", "sample_serial": "01", "parameters": [ { "param1": "param1", "param2": "param2", "param3": "param3", "param4": "param4", "param5": "param5", "param6": "param6" }]}]}}' :: jsonb, '$.** ? (@.type() == "object").keyvalue()') AS a
```

Result :

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| code1 | {"obj1": [{"parameters": [{"param1": "param1", "param2": "param2", "param3": "param3", "param4": "param4", "param5": "param5", "param6": "param6"}], "sample_code": "1", "sample_name": "1", "sample_serial": "01"}]} |
| obj1 | [{"parameters": [{"param1": "param1", "param2": "param2", "param3": "param3", "param4": "param4", "param5": "param5", "param6": "param6"}], "sample_code": "1", "sample_name": "1", "sample_serial": "01"}] |
| parameters | [{"param1": "param1", "param2": "param2", "param3": "param3", "param4": "param4", "param5": "param5", "param6": "param6"}] |
| sample_code | 1 |
| sample_name | 1 |
| sample_serial | 01 |
| parameters | [{"param1": "param1", "param2": "param2", "param3": "param3", "param4": "param4", "param5": "param5", "param6": "param6"}] |
| sample_code | 1 |
| sample_name | 1 |
| sample_serial | 01 |
| param1 | param1 |
| param2 | param2 |
| param3 | param3 |
| param4 | param4 |
| param5 | param5 |
| param6 | param6 |
| param1 | param1 |
| param2 | param2 |
| param3 | param3 |
| param4 | param4 |
| param5 | param5 |
| param6 | param6 |

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GlsPVO3i)

Comment: Thanks Edouard but i did it another way .

Comment: sure, can you share your way ?

Comment: I did it in this way .. thanks  [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/0b3Yh8w5)